# Print a value from a list based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to take user input 1-10 and print out the roman numeral of it. So if they enter 5 i need to print 'V'.

```
test = int(input("Enter in a number '1-10' "))
roman = ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"]
if test in range(1, 10):
    for i in range(len(roman)):
        print(test, roman[i])
```

Is what I have but it isn't working like I want. This is what it is spitting out.
Enter in a number '1-10' 5

```
5 I
5 II
5 III
5 IV
5 V
5 VI
5 VII
5 VIII
5 IX
5 X
>>>
```

Comment: See also: [roman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/roman/) on pypi.

Comment: How about `roman = ["nulla", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"]`? Then you can just use `roman[test]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
test = int(input("Enter in a number '1-10' "))
roman = ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"]
if 0 < test <= 10:
     i = roman[test-1]
     print(test, i)
```

Answer (score 3):

No looping required.

```
print test, roman[test - 1]
```

`-1` is because arrays start from 0, and you start from `"I"`